# Error on rake db:migrate with mongrel, "Could not find mongrel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install track, a ruby on rails application on ubuntu 10.04. Bundle install works fine, however when I run rake db:migrate I get some deprecation warnings, and then an error claiming that system "Could not find mongrel" despite the fact that it is installed. If I list the gems mongrel is clearly on the list, but when running rake commands I get this error. Any ideas?

```
Could not find mongrel (~> 1.1.5) amongst [rake-0.9.2.2, RedCloth-4.2.8, 
ZenTest-4.6.1, aasm-2.2.0, activesupport-2.3.14, rack-1.1.0, actionpack-2.3.14, 
actionmailer-2.3.14, activerecord-2.3.14, activeresource-2.3.14, acts_as_list-0.1.4, 
archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2, bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.18, 
columnize-0.3.4, diff-lcs-1.1.2, json-1.5.3, gherkin-2.4.11, term-ansicolor-1.0.6, cucumber-1.0.2, cucumber-rails-0.3.2, daemons-1.0.10, database_cleaner-0.6.7, flexmock-0.9.0, gem_plugin-0.2.3, has_many_polymorphs-2.13, highline-1.5.2, hoe-2.12.0, hpricot-0.8.4, htmlentities-4.3.0, i18n-0.6.0, ruby_core_source-0.1.5, linecache19-0.5.12, mime-types-1.16, polyglot-0.3.2, treetop-1.4.10, mail-2.3.0, memory_test_fix-0.1.3, mongrel-1.2.0.pre2, nokogiri-1.4.7, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-2.3.14, rspec-1.3.2, rspec-rails-1.3.4, ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25, ruby-debug19-0.11.6, ruby-openid-2.1.8, rubycas-client-2.2.1, rubyjedi-actionwebservice-2.3.5.20100714122544, sanitize-1.2.1, selenium-client-1.2.18, soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3, sqlite3-1.3.4, test-unit-1.2.3, thoughtbot-factory_girl-1.2.2, webrat-0.7.3, will_paginate-2.3.16, yard-0.7.3]
```

Answer (score 3):

try to comment mongrel in Gemfile and do:

```
(shell) $ mv ./config/initializers/mongrel_workaround.rb ./tmp/
```

Then, if you have a message like:
"(.../tracks/config/locales/cz.yml): couldn't parse YAML at line 438 column 13.", you can fix it adding those lines in ./config/boot.rb (at the beginning, after RAILS_ROOT=...) :

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

And then finally try again:

```
(shell) $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: did I mention I am using RVM? does that make a difference?

Comment: What about bundle show? Do you see the right version of mongrel? Another thing you might want to try is defining a rvm gemset with a .rvmrc file.